# Повторить число определенное количество раз из многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Входными данными яляется двухмерный массив, в котором каждый вложенный массив будет иметь два числовых значения.
Первое будет значением для повторения, второе будет количеством повторений этого значения.

```
let repeatNumbers = function(data) {
  // Put your solution here
};

console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]));
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
1111111111
11, 222
10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

Функция должна возвращать строку, в которой каждое из заданных значений повторяется соответствующее количество раз, каждый набор значений разделяется запятой. Если есть только один набор значений, нужно пропустить запятую.

Я додумалась только о решении для первого подмассива, как решить, когда подмассивов много пока ума не приложу(

```
let repeatNumbers = function(data) {

  let firstEl = data[0][0].toString();
  return firstEl.repeat(data[0][1]); 
}

console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для обхода внешнего массива используйте `map()`, для повторений - `repeat()`, для запятых - `join()`. вот и все.

```js
var data = [[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]];

var result = data.map(v => v[0].toString().repeat(v[1])).join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Вот же я деревня - не додумалась ( все ведь оказалось так просто. Тяжело быть новичком. Спасибо большое @teran .